# ASP.net Ajax Strange Characters appear when I try to insert data

Tags: asp.net-ajax, telerik

I have a simple form that is used to insert data to a SQL database.

Everything works fine on the local server, but when I publish to my server, upon submission,

I get a response on the page like this,

��������`I�%&/m�{J�J��t��`$ؐ@�����iG#)�*��eVe]f@�흼 ��{���{��;�N'���?\fdl��J�ɞ!���?~|?"��Ey�')=��y6����h���x:͛& m�����*k���'�~�oWM[,/^�2���Ζ�EV�~�U���i5��U3�V����ꪮ���]��*�5���u3ϖ�^]|� M:˗E>?�+�y4�u�A:�f��/>����y�(��G�d^ϲe��!z���Ѳ�Y)5��G��A�8�VeU?������/I=�����Yd�E��n�գt����/�q� �IU�n �ۻ�/No������N�|� �&�}�0��e�uU��?_O�Y��T˦*s�3�0_�/� �ۼV��@ʄJ��TH����m0[��E�|�.�e~���놾J��xQg�a���+�K�>�ڶZ<�����J���\?�`@�}t5/��#���G���{�:�i��)��X���8=^��b�؎�����vwv~���ٮ��YS��������|�(}\�BqZ�:<�B vzN�}��q]d�(�vN�4�Q�y��/�����u�l�_��2�Gi����.��'G�Ӽ���J�������2]/1i%�O�n��wi5��D��5��ɑ�˧k��?�&��U>I�����/���z��YQ62���M�/�_-�u;�n~��d�m�G��!~��������7�nY��� Hd��f���u�T�z��Y$�PK h^�!�v���RA���n���y֤Y:�Į�A�F�V{�"�,K2__�|����/�}�E�G$?;{�ާYL_��UU�M!�u��}�Ӎ���W���yq�fN��UU��c�`|���� ٺ�{�o*5�Ŋ�fE�D���Y�e�*�,������}��Ѻj�z��ow�E{8b���UQ��$��H�*/�5cZ�;����*�����;��B�HS�3Gx��7�̹�1�)�3�yQ�#��) �-�ŧ��węuN�c:�*�a�˺�a�E���<7M^�S�פj��&�yVZ�f� z��� i�6��W��j���&�J 0# �Z/[��#�B/��,�-}#����I����O%���(���j��'��s�F�

I urgently need help friends...

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Do you enabled RadCompression on your site? If so, disable it temporary to see if this stops. Also make sure you use the latest version of the telerik AJAX bundle.